# Checkout form on Product page of Opencart

Tags: opencart, checkout

I am using opencart 2.3.0.2. I want to show checkout form directly on the Product page. The theme installed in Journal2. how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Edit the files:`catalog/view/theme/yourtheme/template/product/product.tpl` and make the following modification:

Find the code:

```
if (json['success']) {
                $('.breadcrumb').after('<div class="alert alert-success">' + json['success'] + '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button></div>');

                $('#cart > button').html('<span id="cart-total"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> ' + json['total'] + '</span>');

                $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');

                $('#cart > ul').load('index.php?route=common/cart/info ul li');
            }
```

Replace With Below Code:

```
if (json['success']) {
    window.location='index.php?route=checkout/checkout'; 
}
```

and then refresh modification cache from admin.
Go to​ admin >​ Extensions > Modifications and click on the blue Refresh button (top right corner) for update the system.​and then check it.​ (If, have available any other cache option in your theme. also, it cache refresh.)

Comment: Thank you for sharing the solution. But unfortunately it doesn't work for me

Comment: I have already check this example. and it is working fine from our side. maybe, will cache issue. Please properly refresh/remove cache after changes. Thanks.